# Block.io ETH alternative

Tags: external-api, blockchain-as-a-service

What's a good Ethereum alternative to [block.io](https://block.io)?

By good I mean, trusted and production ready.

Comment: The full ethereum node better than any kind of middleware(block.io, blockcypher.com and so on)service.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Which of block.io's services do you want an alternative for?

Comment: I want to be able to use ETH blockchain as web service (Rest API). Block.io gives you the ability to create addresses, get address balance, broadcast a signed Tx but also provides web hooks upon given blockchain events, etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Fosha.org](https://www.fosha.org) API, which supports 1000 req/min.

If you would like to test before buying a subscription, you can send us an email (*support@fosha.org*) and we'll send you one with limited validity for free.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a blockchain explorer then try:

https://etherscan.io

Comment: hey thanks, but I'm looking for an API solution. Although etherscan has an API, it is currently very limited.

Comment: Then it is better to run your own Parity or Geth node and interact using web3.py (Python) or web3.js (Node)